# Problem while selecting tags

Tags: support, meta, required-tags

Whenever I used to post question on this site, i was forced to opt bug or feature request as tag. Why so? Is it mandatory for starting members, or bug or something mandatory to all members.

Comment: As the watermark on the tags field says, all questions on Meta "must include at least one of (bug feature-request discussion support)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta is for asking questions about stackoverflow trilogy. The idea is that if you can't find a valid reason to tag your question as [bug], [feature-request], [discussion] or [support], probably that question doesn't belong here.